# Get Email Response of the user

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make a php script that read an email from the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485257/how-to-make-a-php-script-that-read-an-email-from-the-server)

So I want an app to send the user an email, and the user has to respond. How do I capture what the user sent back to the email?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485257/how-to-make-a-php-script-that-read-an-email-from-the-server

Comment: PHP can not receive emails itself. You either need to set up a handler script on your server using `procmail` or use a cron job which polls a mailbox. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20receive%20email

Answer (score 0):

Check the `In-Reply-To` header of the reply to find out which message it relates to.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- Set up a regular off-the-shelf email server, and something to parse the inbox.
- Set up a special php email server that listens on port 22 and processes the incoming mail - something like [james](http://james.apache.org/server/) but php-based. If nothing available you'll have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create some cron job that will retrieve inbox of your email account.

I have implemented simmilar thing but I was using tokens system too - email that was send to user had a random generated token in topic. When user replied I was looking for that token and then associate it with some 'thread' (helpdesk system).